# image shake on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a image shake on mouse over, I got it to shake but it seems to shake constantly rather then on mouseover.

vibrate.js (uses the vibrate plugin http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/vibrate/ )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".bottles").mouseover( function() {

        // configurations for the buzzing effect. Be careful not to make it too annoying!
        var conf = {
                frequency: 6000,
                spread: 7,
                duration: 700
            };

        // this is the call we make when the AJAX callback function indicates a login failure 
        jQuery(this).vibrate(conf);
    });

});
```

html

```
<div id="bottle">
<img class="bottles" src="/images/_garlic.png">
</div>
```

How would I stop that function from shaking?

Comment: You can just undelete your old question, no need to ask another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713900/image-shake-on-mouse-over

Comment: Do you have an example page up?

Comment: It's shaking randomly. It does grab the attention ;)

Comment: @Nick - Can <10K users undelete old questions?

Comment: @Peter - I'm not sure... they *should* be able to when they're self deleted if they aren't already able to do so, but good point:)

Comment: @Nick @Peter - No they can't. Heck...I can't even see questions that I deleted. All you high falootin-tootin >10k rep guys...you forget what it's like to be a peon down here in the ranks fighting for the scraps of rep you drop. ;-) :-p

Comment: @JasCav - You have more rep then me fwiw ;)  I still see my deleted answers, so I thought there may be a way to see your own deleted questions (even though they don't show up in your questions list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it shakes constantly is that the plugin is set up to create an element that shakes intermittently.... for ever. The shake is produced with **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)**. setInterval is also used to trigger the intermittent periods of shaking.

Working from **[the plugin by Andreas Lagerkvist you linked to](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/vibrate/)**, just remove the never ending intermittent shakes by removing the setInterval() call to doVibration(). Then you can set how long you want it to vibrate on a hover (you don't want it to vibrate the **entire** time someone hovers... do you? that'd be annoying)

Put what you want to vibrate in a div and trigger the vibration with a **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**. The advantage of hover is that it vibrate on both mouseenter and mouseleave if the user stops their mouse over the div.

```
$('#jquery-vibrate-example').hover(function() {$(this).vibrate();});
```

If you only want it to vibrate once just use **[.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)**

```
$('#jquery-vibrate-example').mouseenter(function() {$(this).vibrate();});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gkw8n/)**

When you call `.vibrate()` you can pass the speed, duration, and spread (I removed frequency) in as parts of an object literal to fine tune the vibration: `$(this).vibrate({"speed":100,"duration":800,"spread":5});` for example. The larger the `speed` the slower it shakes, since `speed` is used directly in the `setInterval()` of the shaking. The other two are self explanatory:

```
jQuery.fn.vibrate = function (conf) {
    var config = jQuery.extend({
        speed:        30, 
        duration:    1000,  
        spread:        3
    }, conf);

    return this.each(function () {
        var t = jQuery(this);

        var vibrate = function () {
            var topPos    = Math.floor(Math.random() * config.spread) - ((config.spread - 1) / 2);
            var leftPos    = Math.floor(Math.random() * config.spread) - ((config.spread - 1) / 2);
            var rotate    = Math.floor(Math.random() * config.spread) - ((config.spread - 1) / 2);

            t.css({
                position:            'relative', 
                left:                leftPos + 'px', 
                top:                topPos + 'px', 
                WebkitTransform:    'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)'  // cheers to erik@birdy.nu for the rotation-idea
            });
        };

        var doVibration = function () {
            var vibrationInterval = setInterval(vibrate, config.speed);

            var stopVibration = function () {
                clearInterval(vibrationInterval);
                t.css({
                    position:            'static', 
                    WebkitTransform:    'rotate(0deg)'
                });
            };

            setTimeout(stopVibration, config.duration);
        };
        doVibration();
    });
};
```

---

**Note:** The plugin changes the positioning of your shaking item to `relative`... so you'll get funny results if you apply it to an originally `absolute`ly positioned element.

Comment: Here's [a variation of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gkw8n/307/) with multiple nested vibrating elements. It produces a very interesting effect, which resembles vibrating curtains.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Nice! I like it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the source of this page: (view source then scroll down)

http://www.bennadel.com/resources/demo/jquery_vibrate_plugin/