# Dynamically change style of all <img> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am trying to simulate shaking by changing the position of img tags within a div.

I have it working for one img at a time.

Is there a way to change the style of all the img tags within a div at once?

This is what I am currently doing:

```
bird = document.createElement('img');
bird.setAttribute('src',birdie);
bird.setAttribute('class', 'birdie');
bird.setAttribute('id', id);
bird.setAttribute('onLoad', 'shakeAll()');
map.appendChild(bird);
birds++;
if(birdmap[0] == 0){
    birdmap = [id];
}else{
    birdmap+=[,id];
}
```

this `ShakeAll` function is also at `onLoad` of body:

```
function shakeAll(){
    if (birdmap[0] == 0) return;
    i = 1;
    while(i <= birds){
        shakeIt(birdmap[i]);
        i++;
    }
setTimeout("shakeAll()",initialSpeed);
}
```

Note: the imgs are absolute

```
function shakeIt(id){
     shake = document.getElementById(id);
     j=1;
    while(j<4){
     if (j==1){
      shake.style.top=parseInt(shake.style.top)+distance+"px";
     }
     else if (j==2){
      shake.style.left=parseInt(shake.style.left)+distance+"px";
     }
     else if (j==3){
      shake.style.top=parseInt(shake.style.top)-distance+"px";
     }
     else{
      shake.style.left=parseInt(shake.style.left)-distance+"px";
     }
     j++;
    
    }
     //setTimeout("shakeIt(id)", 50);
}
```

Comment: Assuming that bird refers to the containing html element, bird.getElementsByTagName("img") will give you an array of image elements. 
Is there any reason you're creating the html elements with js?

Comment: Personally, I'd make life a lot easier and use jquery.  See this stack overflow <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713961/image-shake-on-mouse-over">discussion.</a>
There's a few other demos/classes/libraries out there that might help. 
It may even be as simple as the <a href="http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce">jQuery Bounce</a> function depending on the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't really tell what you were trying to do in your code.  Here's some code that shows the basics of moving some images back and forth:

```
// quadratic easing in/out - acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
// t = time into the animation
// d = duration of the total animation
// b = base value
// c = max change from base value (range)
var easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
    return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
};

var linearTween = function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*t/d + b;
};

// cubic easing in/out - acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
var easeInOutCubic = function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
};


function shakeAll() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");

    // save away original position
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].basePos = parseInt(imgs[i].style.left, 10);
    }

    var numShakes = 0;
    var maxShakes = 10;
    var range = 100;
    var direction = 1;
    var duration = 300;   // ms
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var deltas = [];

    function shakeImgs() {
        var now = (new Date()).getTime();
        var elapsed = Math.min(now - startTime, duration);
        var delta = Math.round(easeInOutQuad(elapsed, 0, range, duration));
        delta *= direction;
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            var basePos = imgs[i].basePos;
            if (direction < 0) {
                basePos += range;
            }
            imgs[i].style.left = (basePos + delta) + "px";
        }
        if (now - startTime >= duration) {
            startTime = now;
            direction *= -1;
            ++numShakes;
        }
        if (numShakes < maxShakes) {
            setTimeout(shakeImgs, 10);
        }
    }

    shakeImgs();
}
```

Working demo and HTML shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ED5yA/

And, here's a fun one that adds some random shakiness (jitter) to the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jM8jx/.

The basics of obtaining the list of images to operate on is this part:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

This gets the container object and then gets all image objects in that container.  You can see the corresponding HTML in the jsFiddle.  This code implements a positioning scheme that slows the velocity down at the edges and goes the fastest in the middle of the range.  The rest of the motion is controlled by the intial value of the variables declared in `shakeAll()`.  These can be edited or can be changed to be passed into the function.

Answer (score 1):

give a common class name to all imgs that you wanna shake. and then, user [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) instead of getElementById() to return an array of the elements which have the specific class name. then use a loop to animate each.

but if you want ALL imgs to be animated, use [element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) or [document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) instead.